# Collect the result with only a stream (without external loop use)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there a way to do the following code only with lambdas ?

```
// translate someList1 to someList3
// .. get sublist
List<String> someList2 = someList1.stream()
        .map(i -> i.getField())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
// .. create new (target) list
List<SomeClass> someList3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (String item : someList2) {
    SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass();
    someObj.setField(item);
    someList3.add(someObj);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just one collect is required :

```
List<SomeClass> someList2 = 
someList1.stream()
         .map(i -> {                    
                    SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass();
                    someObj.setField(i.getField());  
                    return someObj;
                  }
         )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But note that with a constructor  in `SomeClass` that accepts the value of `getField()`, it would be really more neat :

```
List<SomeClass> someList2 = 
someList1.stream()
         .map(i-> new SomeClass(i.getField())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or by spliting the `map()` operation in two distinct transformations, you can use method references, which improves the readability :

```
List<SomeClass> someList2 = 
someList1.stream()
         .map(OneClass::getField)
         .map(SomeClass::new)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a multiline lambda and another map operation:

```
List<SomeClass> someList3 = someList1.stream()
    .map(i -> i.getField())
    .map(f -> {
        SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass();
        someObj.setField(f);
        return someObj;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to `map` it to a `String` then back to `SomeClass`, do it in the one map:

```
 List<SomeClass> someList2 = list.stream()
            .map(i -> new SomeClass(i.getField())) //in case you have such constructor 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```